# Command line tool (or code) to sign and/or check digital signature on an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, code-signing

For EXE and MSI files that we produce, we use signtool.exe from the SDK on our build server.

We also produce XLS files that have macros in them. We don't build them, but we package them up using the build server. I have not found a way to sign the XLS file from a command line. It seems that the only way to do it is through the Excel application UI.

If there is no way to sign the XLS file from command line I'd like for our build server to at least VERIFY, that the XLS files, that it gets from source control, are signed.

signtool.exe doesn't support XLS files. Is there anything that can do either the signing, the verification or both?

Comment: It looks like this could be helpful: Upgrade signed Office VBA macro projects to V3 signature (KB5000676) It says: "SignTool in the Windows 10 SDK can help you re-sign the VBA files through a command line." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/upgrade-signed-office-vba-macro-projects-to-v3-signature-kb5000676-2b8b3cae-ad64-4b4b-aa85-c4a98ca6da87